# Is null condition in the predicate on Distributed Query does not run remote

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am executing the below distributed query  with predicate condition but it is not executing the code completely remote.

This is happening only for IS NULL predicate on BIT column

```
Select * from [RemoteServer].[DBName].dbo.[TableName] where [column] is null
```

The distributed server in this case is SQL Server and the Column is BIT data type.

For this, the remote query is pulling all the data back to the main server and then applying the filter.

The execution plan looks like this..

[image: Click here to see the execution plan]

This only happens if I check for Is null condition. If I do, `[column]=1` or `Column=0`, then the query runs remotely.

Comment: Possibly depends on your linked server definition. Is it using `SQLNCLI` or something else?